# multiple charts in a single frame using html

Tags: html

I have 4 graphs.How can i put more than a three graphs in a single frame set in html? I'm getting graph [image]

but want it like as

[image]

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#99CCFF">

 <div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="placeholder" ></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the chart divs into a table with two columns or use CSS/inline styles to float them next to each other.

The latter can be achieved by changing your div statements to

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
```

Or by adding CSS to the head section of the HTML:

```
<style>
  div.placeholder{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
  }
</style>
```